# If selector exists - run code else repeat check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if a selector exists, if it does I would like it to run some code, if it doesn't I would like it to repeat the check.

The reason I want to do this is because I know an element WILL exist, but I will not know when.

Something like this:

```
if ($(.element).length ) {
    // Do something
}else{
//check again
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if ($(".youtube5player").length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // Do stuff
    }
}, 100);
```

What this does is use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to perform a check approximately every 100 ms to see if your selector returns any results. If it does, the interval is cleared and the code will not run again.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rBdFP/

Answer (score 4):

Besides using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) you can also use a recursive setTimeout pattern like the following:

```
(function doCheck(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($(.element).length ) {
            // Do something
        }else{
            //check again
            doCheck();
        });
    }, 100);
})();
```

While it doesn't seem likely in your case see there are times where using setInterval is considered harmful. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval):

> If there is a possibility that your logic could take longer to execute
>   than the interval time, it is recommended that you recursively call a
>   named function using window.setTimeout.  For example, if using
>   setInterval to poll a remote server every 5 seconds, network latency,
>   an unresponsive server, and a host of other issues could prevent the
>   request from completing in its alloted time.  As such, you may find
>   yourself with queued up XHR requests that won't necessarily return in
>   order.
>
> For such cases, a recursive setTimeout pattern is preferred

Comment: A recursive method will also slowly build up a huge call stack in memory unlike the other methods. ECMAScript 6 has Tail Call optimizations, but ECMAScript 4 did not.